# Solaris timezone in C (missing %z on strftime)

Tags: c, solaris, strftime

I have an application that writes to another application and needs to provide the date + timezone of the system. I have been using strftime with the `%z` argument to get the timezone, and it has been working very well on Linux. However, last week we decided to merge it to solaris just to find out that `%z` is not present.

Someone suggested to use `%Z`, which will give the timezone name, but I need the %z which gives the timezone with the offset format, like `+0100` or `-0300`.

Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%z is not POSIX. You will have to calculate the offset yourself by finding the difference between localtime and gmtime.

For a Perl example, [see here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2003/01/msg39201.html).