# Using strftime in C, how can I format time exactly like a Unix timestamp?

Tags: c, strftime

Here's the sort of time formatting I'm after:

```
2009-10-08 04:31:33.918700000 -0500
```

I'm currently using this:

```
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", ts);
```

Which gives:

```
2009-10-11 13:42:57 CDT
```

Which is close, but not exact. I can't seem to find anything on displaying `-0500` at the end. Plus I'm getting the seconds as an int.

How can I resolve these two issues?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
    char            fmt[64], buf[64];
    struct timeval  tv;
    struct tm       *tm;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    if((tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec)) != NULL)
    {
            strftime(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%%06u %z", tm);
            snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt, tv.tv_usec);
            printf("'%s'\n", buf); 
    }
```

Fixes for the problems you had:

- Use `gettimeofday()`, and `struct timeval`, which has a microseconds member for the higher precision.
- Use a two-step approach, where we first build a string containing all the data except the microseconds.
- Use lower-case 'z' for the timezone offset. This seems to be a GNU extension.

I tried re-creating the timezone offset manually, through the second `struct timezone *` argument of `gettimeofday()`, but on my machine it returns an offset of 0 which is not correct. The [manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/gettimeofday.2.html) for `gettimefday()` has quite a lot to say about the handling of timezones under Linux (which is the OS I tested on).

Comment: `%z` is still non-standard =)

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest I've gotten so far. The '%%06u' is just throwing garbage data back at me right now but the rest works well.

P.S Yes, I know the %z is non-standard, but I'll take it :)

Comment: @aditya: That's weird ... The code above should work. Make sure you provide the second snprintf() call with a proper unsigned microseconds value to use for the %06u format. You can try printing the result after the strftime() call, you should see your final output except for the %06u sequence after the period.

Comment: It seems everyone here have missed the fact that %z is completely standard C99. It's in (the freely available) draft n1256 (tc3 working paper) as well as the official standard document, and it is also specified in POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html).

Comment: `tv.tv_usec` is type `suseconds_t`.  Have not found a % modifier for it.  Maybe a cast to (unsigned long) and use `%06lu`.  (or cast to (uintmax_t) and use PRIuMAX.

Comment: I think the reason %%06u is throwing garbage is because the usec may be a long int, not an int.  So you may need to use %%06lu instead.

Comment: `%z` can be also printed using `timezone::tz_minutewest` or `tm::tm_gmtoff`. The last one seems to be non-standard, though.

Answer (score 1):

%z (lower case z).

However, this does not appear in the [Posix specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html). Google took me in a circle [back here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172318/solaris-timezone-in-c-missing-z-on-strftime).

Answer (score 1):

`"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"`, but it seems `%z` is a GNU extension.

Comment: %T does not give the sub-second digits asked for in the question.